# Building a C# tokenizer for JSON arrays that supports exceptions

Tags: c#, tokenize

I need to tokenize JSON arrays to convert them into an `Object[,]`.

The format will be something like:

```
[[1,"2"],[",]",5]
```

which would translate into

```
string json = @"[[1,""2""],["",]"",5]]";
```

for the matrix:

```
1       "2"
",]"    5
```

What would be the easiest way to tokenize this in C# since splitting will not work as the string may contain the split character (but escaped)?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be using an already existing JSON library.

Comment: Please, add a sample JSON. Is your string like "[[1,\"2\"],[\",]\",5]"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
string json = @"[[1,""2""],["",]"",5]]";
var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[][]>(json);
```

or using [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
var arr = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object[][]>(json);
```

Comment: At the moment, I have a requirement to try to avoid using external libraries.

Comment: @leppie If what you say is the difference between two-dim array and jagged array, then this is all I can do. Post your own answer.

Comment: @I4V: That is what I am saying. You can just add that it is not exactly the same thing. I dont have an answer for a multidimensional array either :)

Comment: @leppie I think everybody knows now :)